# Arithmetic error when calculating inverse of the logistic?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms, exponentiation, transformation

I would like to rearrange the logistic function:

$$y=\frac1{1+\exp(-a+bx)}$$

To calculate $x=f(y)$

So I did the following:

$$\frac1{y}=1+\exp(-a+bx)$$
$$\ln\left(\frac1{y}-1\right)=-a+bx$$
$$\frac{\ln\left(\frac1{y}-1\right) +a}{b}=x$$

but when I try to plot this function, it appears that I have lost a '-' somewhere, i.e., I have calculated $-x=f(y)$

Where I have missed the negative sign?

Comment: Are you sure your original function is written correctly? Shouldn't $x$ have a negative coefficient?

Comment: @Qiaochu Do you mean $y=\frac{-1}{1+\text{exp}(-a+bx)}$?

Answer (score 1):

I am not allowed to comment, so I will answer.  First, your algebra is correct.  If you plotted it, you must have specified numeric values for a, b.  I tried a=2, b=1 and the plots looked totally inverse, just as they should [except the sigmoid was decreasing i.e. reflected in y-axis as compared to usual logistic], so if your plots did not look inverse to each other, what values of a,b did you use?  If you tell us that, perhaps we could say more.

Comment: @Rita; +1 and hope that you give answers instead of comments in the future so you can eventually down vote. Also, you get +100 in reputation by adding another site. So click here while logged in as Rita the dog: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/ .

Comment: @Carl:  thanks, signed onto meta but so far no bonus.  Maybe there is a delay.

Comment: @Rita; Ooops. Now that I read more, it seems that this only applies in getting starting rep in a new area when you already have rep somewhere else in excess of 200. See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35033/bonus-points-for-merging-accounts But having looked at your other comments, I believe you will be at the 200 level in a week or two at most.

Comment: @Rita I was using $[a,b]= [-20.6, 0.25]$, a maximum likelihood fit for a logistic regression model to data. I was trying to invert the equation to predict x from y, but apparently I made the mistake of starting with the wrong equation.

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is indeed correct. For $y \in (0,1)$ you'll get a function decreasing from $+\infty$ for $y=0^+$ to $-\infty$ as $y \to 1$ as it should. Remember that the graph of the inverse function is obtained by [mirroring the graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function#Graph_of_the_inverse) around the line $x=y$.